# How can I append a formatted string to an existing String?

Tags: string-formatting, rust

Using [`format!`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.format!.html), I can create a `String` from a format string, but what if I already have a `String` that I'd like to append to? I would like to avoid allocating the second string just to copy it and throw away the allocation.

```
let s = "hello ".to_string();
append!(s, "{}", 5); // Doesn't exist
```

A close equivalent in C/C++ would be [`snprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/).

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I see now that `String` [implements](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#impl-Write) `Write`, so we can use [`write!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.write.html):

```rust
use std::fmt::Write;

pub fn main() {
    let mut a = "hello ".to_string();
    write!(a, "{}", 5).unwrap();

    println!("{}", a);
    assert_eq!("hello 5", a);
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=31daf860b6bf06c8bc05890d27e399ca))

It [is impossible for this `write!` call to return an `Err`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.47.0/library/alloc/src/string.rs#L2414-L2427), at least as of Rust 1.47, so the `unwrap` should not cause concern.

Comment: Note to self: `fmt::Write` and `io::Write` are unrelated.