# Unable to use if expression to append to string instead of if statement

Tags: string, rust, borrow-checker, borrowing

I have the following code that works fine:

```
fn main() {
    let mut example = String::new();

    if 1 + 1 == 2 {
        example += &"string".to_string()
    } else {
        example += &'c'.to_string()
    };

    println!("{}", example);
}
```

When I change the code to this:

```
fn main() {
    let mut example = String::new();

    example += if 1 + 1 == 2 {
        &"string".to_string()
    } else {
        &'c'.to_string()
    };

    println!("{}", example);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:5:10
  |
5 |         &"string".to_string()
  |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ temporary value does not live long enough
6 |     } else {
  |     - temporary value dropped here while still borrowed
7 |         &'c'.to_string()
8 |     };
  |     - temporary value needs to live until here

error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:7:10
  |
7 |         &'c'.to_string()
  |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ temporary value does not live long enough
8 |     };
  |     - temporary value dropped here while still borrowed
  |
  = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are created
```

This makes no sense to me as both snippets seem identical. Why doesn't the second snippet work?

Comment: Hopefully it's an artifact of your example, but this code is not idiomatic. *Especially* code like `&"string".to_string()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you apply `&` to expressions, Rust automatically creates anonymous variables that own the result of the evaluation of the expression. So, your code is roughly equivalent to

```
fn main() {
    let mut example = String::new();

    example += if 1 + 1 == 2 {
        let temp1 = "string".to_string();
        &temp1
    } else {
        let temp2 = 'c'.to_string();
        &temp2
    };

    println!("{}", example);
}
```

As you can now hopefully clearly see, the scope (and the lifetime) of `temp1` is restricted to the `true`-branch of the `if`-expression, and the scope of `temp2` is restricted to the `false`-branch of the `if`-expression. Neither scope / lifetime extends outside of the `if`-expression, so the `String`s inside the both branches of `if` cannot be appended to `example`.

In contrast to that, your first example is roughly equivalent to

```
fn main() {
    let mut example = String::new();

    if 1 + 1 == 2 {
        let temp1 = "string".to_string();
        example += &temp1;
    } else {
        let temp2 = 'c'.to_string();
        example += &temp2;
    };

    println!("{}", example);
}
```

and in both cases `temp1` and `temp2` live long enough so that the content of `String`s can be copied and appended to `example` before `temp1` and `temp2` are dropped.

Comment: @trentcl You are right. I reformulated the last sentence. Hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Wait... I'm still confused by this. Why can't a copy occur in the first example too? I mean, you say that the variables (`temp1` and `temp2`) are both restricted to their respective branches for the first example, but isn't this also true for the second? Why can a copy occur for the first one but not the second?

Comment: @ArnavBorborah the variables `temp1` and `temp2`  never leave their respective curly braces.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah In both cases, `temp1` and `temp2` are dropped when their block ends at a closing curly brace. But the appending `+=` takes place *inside* of the branches in one case, and *outside* of the branches in the other case. If `+=` is outside of the branches, then there are no buffers that could be appended to `example`, because both `temp1` and `temp2` have already been dropped. If `+=` is *inside* of the branches, then everything is fine, because the content of the strings can be appended to `example` with `+=` before `temp1` or `temp2` is dropped.

Comment: @Shepmaster Right now, I cannot really judge whether it's ugly or not (it probably is, because both the OP and the answerer seem to struggle with the borrow-checker). I've merely tried to perform a simple syntactical desugaring step, otherwise preserving the original code as much as possible, while trying to align the `&` with the `"` in the previous line :]

Comment: Perhaps @Shepmaster meant [something like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=c698977fbe0cb4a03990df181eca6d63), which does work, and is ugly. :-)

Comment: @trentcl Would surrounding the entire `if-else` with a pair of round parens before prepending `&` make it a little less ugly? Or what would be a more idiomatic solution? In my honest opinion: I don't find it ugly, I'm actually delighted to see that prepending a `&` in front of the entire `if` "just works", because all the expressions and referencing/dereferencing operators compose in a predictable way, without any strange exceptions or corner-cases.

Comment: AndreyTyukin and Shepmaster, thanks for the detailed explanations. This has actually somewhat enhanced my understanding of the overly enigmatic (;P) borrow checker.

Answer (score 4):

You've [already seen an explanation as to why this code cannot be compiled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53071450/155423). Here's some code that works and is closer to your goal:

```
example += &if 1 + 1 == 2 {
    "string".to_string()
} else {
    'c'.to_string()
};
```

I would not claim this to be idiomatic Rust. One thing that sticks out to me is the needless allocation of `"string"` into a `String`. I'd write this code using [`String::push_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.push_str) and [`String::push`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.push):

```
if 1 + 1 == 2 {
    example.push_str("string");
} else {
    example.push('c');
}
```

If you weren't appending the string, I'd just evaluate it directly:

```
let example = if 1 + 1 == 2 {
    "string".to_string()
} else {
    'c'.to_string()
};
```

I might even use dynamic dispatch (although it's less likely):

```
let s: &std::fmt::Display = if 1 + 1 == 2 { &"string" } else { &'c' };
let example = s.to_string();
```

or

```
use std::fmt::Write;
let mut example = String::new();
let s: &std::fmt::Display = if 1 + 1 == 2 { &"string" } else { &'c' };
write!(&mut example, "{}", s).unwrap();
```

See also:

- [How can I append a formatted string to an existing String?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28333612/155423)

Comment: @trentcl I am embarrassed. On the up side, check out [what I found](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/55516) by going the silly way.

Comment: Thanks for the details on idiomatic Rust for this kind of thing. Have an upvote!