# How do I concatenate a vector of integers into a single integer?

Tags: vector, rust

I'm trying to concatenate all of the contents of a vector into a single number. This would be like `[1, 2, 4] -> 124`. Here's what I have right now:

```
fn sumVector(vec: &Vec<u32>) -> u32 {
    return vec.to_owned().concat();
}
```

This is failing with error

```
error[E0599]: no method named `concat` found for type `std::vec::Vec<u32>` in the current scope
 --> src/lib.rs:2:27
  |
2 |     return vec.to_owned().concat();
  |                           ^^^^^^ method not found in `std::vec::Vec<u32>`
```

Comment: What should `vec![9, 9, ...<1000 more>..., 9, 9]` result in?

Comment: [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423)

Comment: It is misleading to title this function **sum**. By the way, idiomatic Rust uses `snake_case` for variables, methods, macros, fields and modules; `UpperCamelCase` for types and enum variants; and `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` for statics and constants.

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e928bcc5fe70378bacafa49c807a1ad2 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As said in the comments by Stargateur, you can do:

```
fn concat(vec: &[u32]) -> u32 {
    vec.iter().fold(0, |acc, elem| acc * 10 + elem)
}
```

You can also write the same function in imperative style:

```
fn concat(vec: &[u32]) -> u32 {
    let mut acc = 0;
    for elem in vec {
        acc *= 10;
        acc += elem;
    }
    acc
}
```

Comment: Note that this assumes all elements of `vec` are single digit numbers. To be correct for larger numbers as well, multiply by `10^(elem.#digits)` instead of `10`.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [Ortomala Lokni's procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58923655/155423) if your input vector contains single digit integers.

If the vector contains multi-digit integers, the function may not return the intended value. The following `concat_new` function handles this case.

```
fn main() {
    let a = vec![10_i32, 20, 300];

    println!("{:?}", concat_new(&a));
    println!("{:?}", concat(&a));   
}

fn concat_new(vec: &[i32]) -> i32 {
    let t = vec.iter().fold("".to_string(), |acc, x| acc + &x.to_string());
    t.parse::<i32>().unwrap()
}

fn concat(vec: &[i32]) -> i32 {
    vec.iter().fold(0, |acc, elem| acc * 10 + elem)
}
```

Comment: This is a very inefficient way, even ignoring that it's ultimately a string. [How can I append a formatted string to an existing String?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28333612/155423)

Comment: @shepmaster, thanks for the link.but,  I was just highlighting case where multi digit integer would not work.