# How to write string representation of a u32 into a String buffer without extra allocation?

Tags: string, rust, int

I can convert a `u32` into `String` and append it to an existing string buffer like this

```
let mut a = String::new();
let b = 1_u32.to_string();
a.push_str(&b[..]);
```

But this involves allocation of a new string object in the heap.

How to push the string representation of a `u32` without allocating a new `String`?

Should I implement an int-to-string function from scratch?

Comment: Also the question it was marked as a duplicate of, [How can I append a formatted string to an existing String?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28333612/3650362)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`write!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.write.html) and its family:

```rust
use std::fmt::Write;

fn main() {
    let mut foo = "answer ".to_string();

    write!(&mut foo, "is {}.", 42).expect("This shouldn't fail");

    println!("The {}", foo);
}
```

This prints `The answer is 42.`, and does exactly one allocation (the explicit `to_string`).

([Permalink to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=787e2d4904bd7fb88e1f1dd3f86d9a60))