# Why is the format! macro slower than pushing into a String directly?

Tags: string, performance, rust

When I was trying to generate a string, I used both `format!` and directly pushed into a `String`.

Pushing into a `String` directly took ~40 ns/iter while using `format!` took ~80 ns/iter (twice as long).

Why doesn't the compiler optimize `format!` to the fastest possible machine code? Maybe I'm wrong, but one of promises of `format!` is that it should produce the fastest possible code.

Is there a way to make `format!` produce a better code? Or there will always be a speed penalty when using it?

```rust
#![feature(test)]

fn do_push(username: &str, password: &str) -> String {
    let mut body = String::with_capacity(
        "grant_type=password&username=".len()
            + username.len()
            + "&password=".len()
            + password.len(),
    );
    body.push_str("grant_type=password&username=");
    body.push_str(username);
    body.push_str("&password=");
    body.push_str(password);
    return body;
}

fn do_format(username: &str, password: &str) -> String {
    format!(
        "grant_type=password&username={}&password={}",
        username, password
    )
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    extern crate test;
    use test::Bencher;

    #[bench]
    fn bench_push(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| do_push("my_real_login", "with my real password"));
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bench_format(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| do_format("my_real_login", "with my real password"));
    }
}
```

Comment: `format!` cannot know how big to preallocate the string, because the [`Display` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html) doesn't offer such a hint. Therefore while you allocate the ideal string in `do_push`, `do_format` might have to reallocate a bigger string. However a test with `String::new` instead of `String::with_capacity` on my laptop leads to 4 times slower execution so `format!` is still pretty smart.

Comment: You should try [writing the formatted value into the preallocated `String`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28333612/155423) to compare further.

Comment: Err, never mind my comment above, using `write!` in a preallocated string leads to similar times as `format!` so the difference must come from somewhere else in that case.

Comment: What version of the compiler are you using? On my laptop, the difference isn't two-fold, but a mere 30% slower for `format!`. `format!` being a _very complicated_ and customizable macro, it's not too surprising that the compiler would have some trouble optimizing it to the same level as a preallocated string with a bunch of `push` calls.

Comment: I'm using Nightly Rust 1.48.0 on a i5-2430M with `target-cpu=native`.
The difference is probably bigger because of `target-cpu` argument (on my machine it varies between 40% and 50%).

Comment: In my case, using `String::new` instead of `with_capacity` leads to significantly worse performance than `format!`. If you really want to know what is using time where, you'll have to profile. But to offer an intuitive explanation: `do_push` is an inlined, specific, loop-free version of the function, whereas `do_format` runs via `alloc::fmt::format`, which is generic and handles a list of arguments.

Comment: Meh, since I can't edit the links in: [format loop](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.48.0/src/core/fmt/mod.rs.html#1078-1082), and [format! capacity estimation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.48.0/src/alloc/fmt.rs.html#575-576).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Maybe I'm wrong, but one of promises of `format!` is that it should produce the fastest possible code.

This never was a design goal os the formatting machinery. It was designed to compile fast, and I think also for code size. Never for speed.

If you're looking for a faster alternative (not as fast as hand-written formatting, but pretty fast) you can use [`ufmt`](https://docs.rs/ufmt/latest/ufmt/).

But don't forget to allocate the string with the right capacity, the same you're doing for `push_str()`, so it will be a fair comparison. Then use `write!()`.

However, there are exciting news: [some people are working on rewriting the formatting machinery to be faster, and they got exciting results](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/99012). We have what to hope for.