# String Concatenation when Creating a String from a HashMap in Rust

Tags: rust, hashmap, string-concatenation

I am trying to convert a `HashMap` to a `String` where every item is separated by `,` and a key/value pair is represented using the format `key:value`.

For example, a HashMap

```
HashMap::from([
    (1, 5),
    (2, 10),
    (3, 20),
]);
```

should be converted to the String

```
3:20,2:10,1:5
```

My code below appears to work, I am only able to get it to work by using a strange way of concatenating the strings in the closure for `map`. Also do not understand why the first element needed to use `.to_owned()` while the last element uses `.as_str()`.

```rs
.map(|(k, v)| String::from(k.to_string().to_owned() + ":" + v.to_string().as_str()) )
```

Is there a better way to write this?

```rs
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let foo = HashMap::from([
      (1, 5),
      (2, 10),
      (3, 20),
    ]);
    
    let res = foo
        .iter()
        .map(|(k, v)| String::from(k.to_string().to_owned() + ":" + v.to_string().as_str()) )
        .collect::<Vec<String>>()
        .join(",");
    
    println!("{}", res);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use [`format!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/macro.format.html) here:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let foo = HashMap::from([
      (1, 5),
      (2, 10),
      (3, 20),
    ]);
    
    let res = foo
        .iter()
        .map(|(k, v)| format!("{}:{}", k, v))
        .collect::<Vec<String>>()
        .join(",");
    
    println!("{}", res);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=60924825f2401fed0efe3a023f230ba7)

---

If you really want to avoid unnecessary allocation for the `Vec` and intermediate `String`s (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28333612/how-can-i-append-a-formatted-string-to-an-existing-string)) you could adopt a slightly different approach and do this with a fold:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::fmt::Write;

fn main() {
    let foo = HashMap::from([(1, 5), (2, 10), (3, 20)]);

    let res = foo.iter().fold(String::new(), |mut s, (k, v)| {
        if !s.is_empty() {
            s.push(',');
        }
        
        write!(s, "{}:{}", k, v).expect("write! on a String cannot fail");
        s
    });

    println!("{}", res);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c08f38c7fac01200d377c1e5d8e18130)